# R Programming: How to arrange the ticks values in datetime plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plot dates on the x axis and time on the y axis with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192343/plot-dates-on-the-x-axis-and-time-on-the-y-axis-with-ggplot2)

I have these data,

```
Arrival Date
7:50    Apr-19
7:45    Apr-20
7:30    Apr-23
7:30    Apr-24
7:55    Apr-25
7:20    Apr-26
7:30    Apr-27
7:50    Apr-28
8:00    Apr-30
7:45    May-2
8:30    May-3
8:06    May-4
8:25    May-7
7:35    May-8
7:45    May-9
8:02    May-10
7:53    May-11
8:39    May-14
8:14    May-15
8:08    May-16
8:27    May-17
8:20    May-18
12:00   Apr-19
12:00   Apr-20
12:00   Apr-23
12:00   Apr-24
12:00   Apr-25
12:00   Apr-26
12:00   Apr-27
12:00   Apr-28
11:50   Apr-30
12:00   May-2
11:45   May-3
11:50   May-4
12:00   May-7
11:50   May-8
11:55   May-9
12:10   May-10
11:53   May-11
11:54   May-14
11:40   May-15
11:54   May-16
11:45   May-17
12:00   May-18
```

And I want to plot it using ggplot,

This is what I did,

```
OJT <- read.csv(file = "Data.csv", header = TRUE)

qplot(Date,Arrival, data = OJT, xlab = expression(bold("Date")), ylab = expression(bold("Time"))) + theme_bw() + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90)) +geom_point(size = 2, colour = "black", fill = "red", pch = 21)
```

And here is the output

[image]

As you can see, the time and date is not arrange. I want the time to start from 7:00 am to 12:20 pm, and the date from April 19 to May 18. I tried using

```
as.Date(strptime(OJT$Date,"%m-%dT"))
```

But still I don't get the right plot.

And I can't find similar problems through the internet.

Any idea to help me solve this.

Thanks

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but never tried yet. I'm trying now.

Comment: Sort will not work. You need to convert your dates with `as.Date` or `POSIXct` objects, and your time to `POSIXct` objects.  Then the plot should work. If you post a reproducible example, someone might be able to help.

Comment: I still can't achieved it, please help me arrange that. :(

Comment: Voting to close since this has nothing to do with ggplot2, and everything to do with dealing with real DateTimes and not just character (or factor) data. Read ?DateTimeClasses or the help for lubridate package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try a different approach with some wrangling in `lubridate`. Target plot:

[image: date-hour plot]

The code, including your data:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("lubridate")

df <- read.table(text = "Arrival Date
7:50    Apr-19
7:45    Apr-20
7:30    Apr-23
7:30    Apr-24
7:55    Apr-25
7:20    Apr-26
7:30    Apr-27
7:50    Apr-28
8:00    Apr-30
7:45    May-2
8:30    May-3
8:06    May-4
8:25    May-7
7:35    May-8
7:45    May-9
8:02    May-10
7:53    May-11
8:39    May-14
8:14    May-15
8:08    May-16
8:27    May-17
8:20    May-18
12:00   Apr-19
12:00   Apr-20
12:00   Apr-23
12:00   Apr-24
12:00   Apr-25
12:00   Apr-26
12:00   Apr-27
12:00   Apr-28
11:50   Apr-30
12:00   May-2
11:45   May-3
11:50   May-4
12:00   May-7
11:50   May-8
11:55   May-9
12:10   May-10
11:53   May-11
11:54   May-14
11:40   May-15
11:54   May-16
11:45   May-17
12:00   May-18", header=TRUE)

df$Date <- paste('2012-',df$Date, sep='')
df$Full <- paste(df$Date, df$Arrival, sep=' ')
df$Full <- ymd_hm(df$Full)
df$decimal.hour <- hour(df$Full) + minute(df$Full)/60

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Full, y=decimal.hour)) +
    geom_point()
p
```

Comment: I got it already, actually, almost the same with the one you did gauden. But I convert it to decimal hour in excel, and then I import it and plot it.  But, I'm happy that you should me how to do it in R. Thank you so much Gauden!

Comment: Thanks you to those who made some effort for this question!

Answer (score 1):

```
#make some data in your kind of format:

tS <- dummySeries()
a<-rownames(tS)
x<-c(a,a)
y<-1:24
dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

#get it in the format for the plot

v<-paste(dat$x,dat$y, sep=" ") 
v2<-as.POSIXct(strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d %H",tz="GMT"))
v3<-sort(v2)
hrs<-strftime(v2,"%H")
days<-strftime(v2,"%Y-%m-%d")
final<-data.frame(cbind(days,hrs))
qplot(days,hrs,data=final) + geom_point()

#ooooff... I bet this can be done much cleaner...i know little about 
#time series data.
```

[image]

Comment: this is like what @andrie said but I made your date and arrival one `POSIXct` object first then took out the dates and times for plotting.   I just worked out this route first.